# circle -> disk, rectangle ->?

Tags: single-word-requests

"circle" is usually considered as a "hollow disk".

But what would be a solid counterpart of rectangle?  I am looking for single word here.

Update, little bit of context:

The word will be used to describe an entity in programming. Challenge there is that some systems use underscore convention (filled_rectangle) and others  camel case naming convention (filledRectangle). I need something agnostic to that - single words are preferable in this case.

The word is used in two dimensional graphics context. Programmers are a bit mathematicians so they know that "circle" is such a curved line. And yet they well know the difference between polyline and polygon.

Comment: "(an empty) frame" is the first thing I could think.

Comment: That would be "rectangle", isn't it? Or you mean frame -> rectangle ?

Comment: "circle" - "set of all points in a plane that are at a given distance from a given point, the centre" so mathematically speaking it is just points on the curve.

Comment: Formal mathematical usage is not the "usual" usage.

Comment: @JEL I am using it to describe an entity in programming. Challenge there is that some systems use filled_rectangle (underscore convention) and others filledRectangle (camel case naming convention). I need something agnostic to that - single words are preferable in this case.

Comment: I'm flummoxed and disappointed that this question is considered off-topic. I read [On Topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Per that document, this question fits into the category of "Word choice and usage". Also, some advice for the powers-that-be-here, a question *should not* be deemed "off topic" only because it has benefits in a programming context. The precision and clarity demanded by programming is not something to be dismissed. Most writers could learn a *lot* from programmers! The art of choosing the right terms is hugely important; please let programmers help us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a term having the same relationship to 'rectangle' that 'disk' (in the sense of 'a filled circle') has to 'circle', the best I can offer is 'panel':

> **II.** A distinct part of a surface, and related uses.
>    * A distinct section, typically *rectangular in shape*, that forms part of the whole *surface* of something.
>   ....
>   **d.** *fig.* and in extended use. Something resembling a panel in shape and relation to the surrounding space.

["panel, n.1". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136796?rskey=YLdFix&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed March 02, 2016). Emphasis mine.]

I doubt that panel-throwing will ever be a new Olympic sport.

---

One possible alternative, perhaps more suited to your use, is 'pane':

> b. Computing. A separate defined area within a window for the display of, or interaction with, a specified part of that window's application or output, often one of two or more such areas into which a window is subdivided.

["pane, n.2". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136780?rskey=Eh885p&result=2&isAdvanced=false (accessed March 02, 2016).]

While 'pane' does connote the integrity of the area defined by the shape, it seems to me to be less closely associated with a rectangular shape than 'panel'.

Answer (score 1):

Both ***circle*** and ***rectangle*** are regularly used to mean *both* their perimeters and the solid areas inside them.

If you really want to emphasize that it's filled, you can call it a ***filled rectangle***, or a ***solid rectangle***.

You might be able to get away with ***pane***, which means "a single sheet of glass in a window or door" ([here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/pane)). Some might use this word more generally to mean any filled rectangle (but I'm not sure).

Comment: As I said above two words are not desirable unfortunately.

Comment: Re: "Both circle and rectangle are regularly used to mean both their perimeters and the solid areas inside them." The OP wants precision; not simply common (often careless) usage.

Answer (score 0):

If to forget about "rectangle" then what about "frame" and "block"?

Answer (score -1):

The question really should be "circle->disk as x->rectangle". The term "rectangle" describes both the boundary and the interior of the polygon.
If you're looking for the solid counterpart of "rectangle", it is, in fact, "rectangle". 
Now that that's out of the way, I assume your question will probably be to ask **"disk is to circle as rectangle is to *x*"**. In short: I'm not aware of any such singular word, however the phrase **"the [boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)) of the rectangle"** should work. 
Edit: I can almost guarantee you that "boundary of a rectangle" should match your needs; I just checked the topology section of my Analysis textbook. 

Additional note: non-mathematicians will commonly use the word "circle" to refer to both the boundaries and the interior of a disk.

Comment: You've got it wrong. From Wikipedia: "A circle is a shape consisting of all points in a plane that are at a given distance from a given point, the centre." / "In geometry, a disk ... is the region in a plane bounded by a circle.". These definitions match MathWorld, an authoritative source for mathematical terminology.